# Is exterior algebra an example of an algebra over a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra

An algebra over a field is a pair $(V,\cdot)$ where $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ with a bilinear product $\cdot:V\times V\to V$. In the Szekeres' book on Mathematical Physics, he explains exterior algebra $\bigwedge(V)$ over a vector space $V$ as an example of that definition. But I'm feeling that the wedge product is not closed, meaning that if $u,v\in V$, then $u\wedge v$ does not belong to $V$. Am I feeling right? If so, Is there some structure which the exterior algebra is an example of (something like "algebra over a vector space", I googled it but didn't find any references)?

Comment: If $u,v\in V$, then $u\wedge v$ does not belong to $V$, but it surely belongs to $\bigwedge(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exterior algebra (generated by a vector space $V$) is an algebra. It is the quotient of the tensor algebra $TV$ by the relation $xy+yx=0$ for all $x,y\in V$. I think you are confusing what is the algebra and what is the vector space. $V$, in this context, does not form an algebra under the wedge product. However, the vector space $\Lambda(V)$ does. We have a bilinear map
$$
\wedge:\Lambda(V)\times \Lambda(V)\to \Lambda(V)
$$
The elements of $\Lambda(V)$ look very different than those of $V$. In fact, if $\{e_{i}\}$ is a basis of $V$, an homogeneous element of degree $n$ of $\Lambda(V)$ will look like a linear combination
$$
\sum_{i_1\leq i_2\leq ...\leq i_n\leq k} \alpha_{i_1i_2... i_n}e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge ... \wedge e_{i_n},
$$ 
where $V$ has dimension $k$.

Comment: Perfect, this answered all my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $V$ in $\wedge V$ is a *vector space*, not *vector field* (just to fix the terminology). As egreg pointed out, if $u,v\in V$, then $u\wedge v$ is not an element of $V$, but it is an element of $\wedge^2 V\subset \wedge V$. The algebra $\wedge V$ is really *constructed* in such a way that you will have a correctly defined operation $\wedge$ on it. In a certain sense, it is the smallest *algebra* which contains *vector space* $V$ and has a skew-commutative multiplication.

You can read very detailed explanation of the object $\wedge V$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

Comment: Sorry, "vector field" was a lapse of my mind. So exterior algebra definitely isn't an algebra over a field. Is okay with literature to call algebras those whose products aren't closed, like exterior and clifford algebras? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @IberêKuntz, the exterior algebra _is_ an algebra and is closed under the wedge product operation. I think you need to review what the "exterior algebra" of $V$ actually is.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, how can it be closed if from two vectors from $V$ I get a result out of $V$? What I'd like to know is if there's some structure more general than an algebra over a field and which accounts $\bigwedge (V)$ as an algebra indeed (it surely exists, otherwise it wouldn't call exterior algebra I think).